# Join tables (1:n) with considering two records from the second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named `letter` and `letter_person` like this :

`letter` :

```
id | subject | body | time
==========================
 1 |  Hello  | null | ...
 .
 .
 .
```

and `letter_person` :

```
id | ref_person | ref_letter |   role
========================================
 1 |     1      |     1      |   sender
 2 |     2      |     1      |  receiver
 .
 .
 .
```

`role` is an enum field and can be `sender` or `receiver`

i want to select letters which are sent and received between two persons, i want something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM letter
JOIN letter_person ON letter_person.ref_letter = letter
WHERE
(letter_person.ref_person = 1 AND letter_person.role = 'sender') 
OR
(letter_person.ref_person = 2 AND letter_person.role = 'receiver')
```

But it's not exactly what i need.

This query selects all the letters which are sent by person1 + all the letters which are received by person2.

I need to get the conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` to the `letter_person` table twice... once to get the sender, once to get the receiver.  This also has the benefit of allowing you to see the details of the person acting as the sender and receiver:

```
SELECT
    sender.ref_person AS sender_ref_person,
    receiver.ref_person AS receiver_ref_person,
    l.id,
    l.subject,
    l.body,
    l.time
FROM
    letter l
    JOIN letter_person sender
        ON sender.ref_letter = l.id
        AND sender.role = 'sender'
    JOIN letter_person receiver
        ON receiver.ref_letter = l.id
        AND receiver.role = 'receiver'
WHERE
    sender.ref_person = 1
    AND receiver.ref_person = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM letter
JOIN letter_person AS sender ON letter.id = sender.ref_letter AND sender.role = 'sender'
JOIN letter_person AS receiver ON letter.id = receiver.ref_letter_id and receiver.role = 'receiver'
WHERE sender.ref_person = 1
AND receiver.ref_person = 2
```

Credit to The previous answer for pointing out my omission! :-)

This has the benefit of not having to use IN subqueries.  With proper indexes and foreign key definitions, performance should be fantastic.

Comment: Michael Fredrickson beat me to the punch (plus his answer was 100% correct).  Sorry for the duplicate answer.

Comment: No worries.. our answers were only 2 minutes apart, and the answer is intuitive enough that I'm sure that you came up with the answer independently...

Answer (score 1):

You can do some think like this

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5de8/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table letter(id int, subject varchar(10));
create table letter_person(id int, ref_person int, ref_letter int, role varchar(1));

insert into letter values(1, 'hello1');
insert into letter values(2, 'hello2');

insert into letter_person values(1, 1, 1, 's');
insert into letter_person values(1, 2, 1, 'r');
insert into letter_person values(1, 3, 2, 's');
insert into letter_person values(1, 2, 2, 'r');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT l.* FROM letter l
INNER JOIN letter_person lps ON l.id = lps.ref_letter AND lps.ref_person = 1 AND lps.role='s'
INNER JOIN letter_person lpr ON l.id = lpr.ref_letter AND lpr.ref_person = 2 AND lpr.role='r'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5de8/2/0)**:

```
| ID | SUBJECT |
|----|---------|
|  1 |  hello1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM letter
JOIN letter_person ON letter_person.ref_letter = letter
WHERE 
(letter_person.ref_person = 1 AND letter_person.role = 'sender') 
AND letter_person.ref_letter in (
    SELECT letter_person.ref_letter FROM letter_person
    WHERE
    (letter_person.ref_person = 2 AND letter_person.role = 'receiver')
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Is it an optimized query to select two times in a query ? Are you sure that there isn't there any other way ?